# Why is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{-2}\delta(1/x) dx=1$?

Tags: integration, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Following the answer by @Carlo Beenakker [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/415009/10059), $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{-2}\delta(1/x) dx=1$, but I failed to understand, why. Can anyone please explain it in simple terms?

Comment: It is not clear in what sense you want to define $x^{-2}\delta_{1/x}$. If it is in the sense of distributions or as a tempered distribution.

Comment: @JeanL. I also do not know in what sense Carlo Beenakker meant this equality. He did not specify.

Comment: $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{-2}\delta(1/x) dx\overset{x\to 1/x}=
 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x) dx=1
$$

Comment: @Quanto but why this substitution is permitted on this improper integral? Is not it not satisfying the conditions for the theorem for substitution?

Comment: @Anixx I have no good reason

Comment: You did not quote what he wrote: "$\delta_{\epsilon}(x)=(2\pi\epsilon)^{-1/2}e^{-x^2/2\epsilon}$,
and $F_\epsilon(x)=x^{-2}\delta_\epsilon(1/x)$. Then $\int_{-\infty}^\infty F_\epsilon(x)dx=1$, for any $\epsilon$, while $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\int_a^b F_\epsilon(x)\,dx=0$."